# Need to develop a query between two table if and else

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two table first is Item master file Col(Icode,IName,UOM) and second table is customer item File Col (Cicode,CIName,CustomerID,UOM,Icode) now i want that when if customer name is mentioned in second item table then item select from customer item File other wise if do not mentioned any item against any customer then item select from item master File.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.

Comment: Sample data required. What you're looking for is to perform an inner join between the 2 tables based on the name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a prioritization query.  You can use `union all` and `not exists`:

```
select . . .   -- whatever columns you want
from customer_items ci
union all
select . . .   -- corresponding columns
from master_items mi
where not exists (select 1
                  from customer_items ci2
                  where ci2.ciname = mi.name
                 );
```

Your question is rather vague on what columns you want and what the names of things really are.  So fill in the `. . .` with the appropriate columns and adjust the names for your situation.

Comment: Gordon Linoff , if first table Item ID Exit in second table then item select from second table ,other wise item select from first table if that item ID does not exit in second table

Comment: @akhterHussain . . . That is what this query does.  You need to provide the columns because they need to match for a `union all` query.